# Find 2d-3d point correspondences without features or descriptors?

Tags: opencv, math, computer-vision

I have a computer vision problem set out like this:

There are some white circles on a black wall in random positions.
There is a calibrated camera, and I have camera frames of the wall, and the circles.

[image]

What I want to do is map the 3d locations of the circles in a structure from motion approach, however, due to the lack of image features, I cannot use feature matching or descriptors, as I normally would.

How can I calculate correspondences in this case?

Currently I am doing the following:

```
Use blob detection to find the circles.
Use optical flow to track the points into the second frame.
Triangulate points between the first and second frames (up to scale).
```

This part works great.

Now, to keep mapping the circles, I run these functions over each set of two frames.

```
Frame A:

Optical flow track the points from previous frame.
Solve pose using PnP from current frame points and 3d map.
Blob detection to get all circles in this frame.
Reproject the 3d points into the frame, and compare point distances with the new points.
If the distance is small, the point exists in 3d. 
Store the other points as 'new' points.

Frame B:

Optical flow track the points from previous frame.
Solve pose from current frame points and 3d map.
Optical flow track the 'new' points from previous frame and triangulate.
add to the 3d map.

repeat.
```

This works, kind of. But is very susceptible to fast motion and error, as expected from a solely optical flow approach.

Is there a better workflow to do structure from motion without descriptor-based feature matching?
Is there a way to find 2d-3d correspondences without using descriptor-based feature matching?
Is there a name for what I am doing that will help me search for similar projects?

Comment: if you can assume that a bigger number of circles is on a single object plane you could use RANSAC homography guessing (choose 4 random possible correspondences until you find a honography that has many inliers).

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. Are you aware of any examples of this that i could use as a starting point?